# Visual Studio Code: Git diff over git gutter indicator

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, diff

In **WebStorm** (and also **Eclipse**, **Netbeans**), when clicking on the *git* diff indicators in the gutter, a contextual menu shows the previous content, and provides a button to quickly revert the block modifications.

[image: WebStorm git diff]

**Visual Studio Code** also provides added/modified/deleted blocks gutter indicators, this way:

[image: VSCode git diff]

But I didn't find how to quickly see the corresponding diff. I can't believe there's no quick way to see what the gutter indicators refer to.

Did I miss something? Is it an upcoming feature? Or would someone know about an extension that would add that behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's here!

It appeared in [Visual Studio Code 1.18](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_git-status-in-file-explorer)!

They call it **Source Control Inline change review**. By the way, they also added coloration over the modified files in the file explorer.

[image: Source Control Inline change review]

Comment: doesn't seem to allow setting the branch to diff to

Answer (score 3):

There currently is no such feature. In general, you should not expect some random feature from one IDE to exist in another editor or it being an “upcoming feature” just because some parts of the UI looks similar. In almost all situations, this won’t be the case.

**However**, in this case, there is actually some kind of work going on, as can be seen in [issue 10782](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10782). You can follow the progress there, or even try to contribute to make it land quicker.

Interestingly, for Visual Studio (not Code), there’s actually an extension that provides this functionality: [GitDiffMargin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentKempe.GitDiffMargin).

Comment: Good to know there's an issue about that! That's not exactly some "random" features. It's something that exists for more than 10 years in Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ for Git, Subversion and other source control tools. I don't know enough the Visual Studio (not Code) suite to know if it exists, but I wouldn't be surprised.
That's why I'm surprised to see feature commonly implemented in the most popular IDEs just half implemented here.

Answer (score 0):

You can install awesome [GitLens — Git supercharged](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension which provide all the functionalities.

Comment: that's just a link with no explanation of how to use it

Comment: you can go through the documentation of extension by yourself :)